# closedResourceError intermittently when using httpx asyncclient to send the request

Tags: python, httpx

I'm observing closedResourceError when sending multiple requests using httpx async client. httpx version used is 0.19.0. Has anyone faced similar issue? if it is an issue and fixed in later version?

**Logs:**

```
resp = await asyncio.gather(*[self.async_send_request(method,self.dest_host,self.dest_port,uri,i,payload=payload,headers=headers) for i in range(int(times) )])
File "/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/ocnftest_lib/scp_Pcf_client.py", line 175, in async_send_request
return await self.conn.request(method,"http://{}:{}{}".format(self.dest_host,self.dest_port,uri),data=payload,headers=headers,allow_redirects=False)
File "/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1494, in request
response = await self.send(
File "/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1586, in send
response = await self._send_handling_auth(
File "/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1616, in _send_handling_auth
response = await self._send_handling_redirects(
File "/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1655, in _send_handling_redirects
response = await self._send_single_request(request, timeout)
File "/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1699, in _send_single_request
) = await transport.handle_async_request(
File "/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 281, in handle_async_request
) = await self._pool.handle_async_request(
File "/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection_pool.py", line 234, in handle_async_request
response = await connection.handle_async_request(
File "/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection.py", line 148, in handle_async_request
return await self.connection.handle_async_request(
File "/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_async/http2.py", line 165, in handle_async_request
return await h2_stream.handle_async_request(
File "/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_async/http2.py", line 339, in handle_async_request
await self.send_headers(method, url, headers, has_body, timeout)
File "/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_async/http2.py", line 398, in send_headers
await self.connection.send_headers(self.stream_id, headers, end_stream, timeout)
File "/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_async/http2.py", line 274, in send_headers
await self.socket.write(data_to_send, timeout)
File "/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/httpcore/_backends/anyio.py", line 77, in write
return await self.stream.send(data)
File "/env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 1116, in send
raise ClosedResourceError
anyio.ClosedResourceError
```

**Sample Code**

```
async def send_request(self,payload,times,method,uri,headers):
resp = await asyncio.gather(*[self.async_send_request(method,self.dest_host,self.dest_port,uri,i,payload=payload,headers=headers) for i in range(int(times) )])
await self.conn.aclose()
log.logger.info("[+] @{} {} {}".format(method,resp[int(times)-1].status_code,uri))
return resp[int(times)-1]

async def async_send_request(self,method,dest_host,dest_port,uri,times,payload=None,headers=None):
  if self.security == 'secure':
      return await self.conn.request(method,"https://{}:{}{}".format(self.dest_host,self.dest_port,uri),data=payload,headers=headers,allow_redirects=False)
  else:
      return await self.conn.request(method,"http://{}:{}{}".format(self.dest_host,self.dest_port,uri),data=payload,headers=headers,allow_redirects=False)

def send_message:
self.conn = httpx.AsyncClient(http2=True,http1=False,proxies=self.proxies,timeout=10)
response = asyncio.run(self.send_request(payload,times,method,uri,headers))
```

Comment: You might be throttled by the server.